# Google Script: Copy row from one sheet to another depending on value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

While ive seen similar questions ive not seen this specific one if im not mistaken.

So, i need to read all the info in a certain column (in this case it would be AF, regardless i havent been using that spreadsheet to try what ive been doing out) and then check whether a cell in that column has the value(or string, sorry new to Google Script) "Finalized" then copy the entire row that corresponds to that cell to a secondary sheet which would store all the finished cases and stuff.

ive been trying to find something thru google but its always how to copy the entire sheet and thats not useful i think, also what ive done rn copies the cells regardless of what the value is on that cell+column

```
function copyIf() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("Stuff"); 
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Terminados");
  var condition = source.getRange('D2:D2000').getValue();
  if (condition == "Terminado") {  
    source.getRange('A2').copyTo(destination.getRange('A2'));
    source.getRange('A3').copyTo(destination.getRange('A3'));
  } 
}
```

i am thinking i should probably implement some sort of for or while loop cause i want this to run constantly so whenever someone changes the status of a certain cell to Terminado to copy that row to the secondary sheet.

Comment: oh and i know its a fairly common question but yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function copyIf() {
  var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stuff");
  var archive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Terminados");
  if (feuille.getLastRow()==1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data!', 'End of script ️')
    return
  }
  var data = feuille.getRange(2,1,feuille.getLastRow()-1,feuille.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  var archiveData = []
  var lignes = []
  var ligne = 1
  var col = 31 // AF
  try {
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      if (row[col]=="Terminado") {
        archiveData.push(row)
        lignes.push(ligne)
      }
    })
    archive.getRange(archive.getLastRow() + 1, 1, archiveData.length, archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData)
    // lignes.reverse().forEach(x => feuille.deleteRow(x));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Rows '+lignes.flat()+' hab been archived !', 'End of script ️')
  } catch (e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data to be archived!', 'End of script ️')
  }
}
```

If you want to delete rows after process, remove `//` before `lignes.reverse().forEach(x => feuille.deleteRow(x));`

Comment: currently testing this solution in my spreadsheet! will comment if anything comes up! thanks

Comment: i had to modify it a bit to fit my usage but this seems to be working perfectly!

Comment: ive accepted the answer! thanks for helping a lil noob like me out