# Google Apps Script - row not deleting after script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Now, about an hour ago someone here was kind enough to help me solve a problem i had with GApps Script, now, while trying to fix/add some stuff, uhhhhh i dont think it works anymore, at least in a certain part.
So, lemme explain, this is the code so far.
Its supposed to check several cases and if the condition is true, it copies those rows from one sheet to the other, this works perfectly, however, (*and this used to work i think, so idk why it doesnt work now*)
the rows that have been copied dont get deleted after that, why is that?

```
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NUEVOS INGRESOS Y EXPEDIENTES EN TRAMITE");
  var archive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CASOS ARCHIVADOS/FINALIZADOS");
  if (sourceSheet.getLastRow()==1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data!', 'End of script ️')
    return
  }
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(2,1,sourceSheet.getLastRow()-1,sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  var archiveData = []
  var lines = []
  var line = 1
  var col = 31 // AF
  try {
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      if (row[col]=="Finalizado_Archivado") {
        archiveData.push(row)
        lines.push(line)
      }
      else if(row[col]=="Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_conexidad"){
        archiveData.push(row)
        lines.push(line)
      }
      else if(row[col]=="Remitida_UACF"){
        archiveData.push(row)
        lines.push(line)
      }
      else if(row[col]=="Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_por_recusacion"){
        archiveData.push(row)
        lines.push(line)
      }
      else if(row[col]=="Remitida_a_otro_Juzgado_por_cuestion_de_turno"){
        archiveData.push(row)
        lines.push(line)
      }
      else if(row[col]=="Remitida_a_otros_fueros"){
        archiveData.push(row)
        lines.push(line)
      }     
    })
    archive.getRange(archive.getLastRow() + 1, 1, archiveData.length, archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData)
    lines.reverse().forEach(x => sourceSheet.deleteRow(x));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Rows '+lines.flat()+' hab been archived !', 'End of script ️')
  } catch (e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data to be archived!', 'End of script ️')
  }
} 

// || "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_conexidad"||"Remitida_UACF"||"Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_por_recusacion"||
//"Remitida_a_otro_Juzgado_por_cuestion_de_turno"||"Remitida_a_otros_fueros"
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the original SO post so that we can compare the reference code and what changes were made?

Comment: @DiegoSanchez yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222804/google-script-copy-row-from-one-sheet-to-another-depending-on-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Changed sheet name
  const ash = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const spA = ["Finalizado_Archivado", "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_conexidad", "Remitida_UACF", "Remitida_a_otro_juzgado_por_recusacion", "Remitida_a_otro_Juzgado_por_cuestion_de_turno", "Remitida_a_otros_fueros"];
  if (ssh.getLastRow() == 1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('No data!', 'End of script ️');
    return;
  }
  const vs = ssh.getRange(2, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
  const archiveData = [];
  let d = 0;//delete counter
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (~spA.indexOf(r[31])) {
      archiveData.push(r);
      ssh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
  ash.getRange(ash.getLastRow() + 1, 1, archiveData.length, archiveData[0].length).setValues(archiveData);
}
```

Comment: im sorry if this comes across as a stupid question, but from what id gather i should execute this function after copying everything using the script i have right?

Comment: edit: nvm, idk why i said that, it has all the stuff needed for checking whether its done copying or not, its just that im having a hard time understanding the code, ima take a while to parse thru it and try to understand it

Comment: Why not just have your app do it?

Comment: so implemented it and it works great!